# "Möge es dir gelingen" vs. "Viel Erfolg"

Tags: phrase, expression

Ich habe eine kleine Frage bezüglich dieser zwei Sätze:

> Möge es dir gelingen.
>   Viel Erfolg!

Welcher der beiden Ausdrücke wird am meisten benutzt und welcher ist (stilistisch) am elegantsten?

Comment: Mögen die Spiele beginnen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Viel Erfolg**

Ist von den beiden Vorschlägen definitiv derjenige, der heutzutage benützt wird. Der Ausdruck wird bestimmt tausendmal so oft wie der andere gebraucht.

Gerne auch benutzt man ihn etwas scherzhaft, wenn der Erfolg sich eigentlich von alleine einstellen müsste:

> Ich gehe mir Essen kaufen.
>   Viel Erfolg!

---

**Möge es dir gelingen.**

Ich bin mir noch nicht einmal sicher, ob ich den Ausdruck als *stilistisch elegant* einstufen möchte. Die Form *möge*, die ich analog zu *man nehme* aus Kochbüchern als Imperativ der 3. Person einstufen würde (wobei mir sicherlich viele widersprechen werden), ist im heutigen gesprochenen Sprachgebrauch völlig unüblich. Vielleicht findest du auf einem oder zwei Mittelaltermärkten jemanden, der dir das sagt, oder ein Spiel, das in einer Fantasywelt oder im Mittelalter spielt, benutzt das in Auftragsvergaben.

Was einige Kommentare richtigerweise hinzufügen: In einigen festen Redewendungen sowie im semi-förmlichen Schriftverkehr hat sich die Form *möge* tatsächlich noch erhalten. Beispiele:

> Möge die Macht mit dir sein! (*May the force be with you*)
>   Möge der Bessere gewinnen!
>   Wer einen besseren Vorschlag hat, möge diesen den Verantwortlichen kundtun.

Würde ich den erfragten Ausdruck selbst (*möge es dir gelingen*) auf der Straße hören, meine Augenbraue wäre so weit hochgezogen, dass man Angst haben müsste, sie schwebte bald über meinem Scheitel.

Comment: Oder auch "Ich geh auf Klo" "Viel Erfolg". Hör ich zumindest öfter.

Comment: „Möge der Bessere gewinnen!“ wäre als feste Wendung nicht so seltsam.

Comment: Und dann war doch gerade May the fourth ;)

Comment: Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Antwort!

Comment: It's pretty much "Good luck" vs. "May you succeed". An obvious choice, wouldn't you say?

Comment: So generell unüblich wie hier dargestellt ist "möge" höchstens im mündlichen Gebrauch. Schriftlich wird es nach wie vor verwendet. Zum einen als "unpersönlicher Imperativ" - wer, so wie ich, dafür Beispiele in seinem E-Mail-Archiv findet, möge diesen Kommentar upvoten. Zum anderen auch, um auf Gratulationskarten Glückwünsche auszudrücken, z.B. "Möge das neue Lebensjahr für Dich viele glückliche Tage bereithalten."

Comment: @Emanuel Gerade den wollte ich jetzt nicht bringen, aber ja, da sage ich das auch regelmäßig ;)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Wie recht du hast. Eingefügt.

Comment: @Matthias Stimmt. Meine Formulierungen waren für *Möge es dir gelingen* gedacht, aber sie sind wahrscheinlich so rübergekommen, als ginge es gegen *möge* im allgemeinen. Ich habs mal verschlimmbessert; ich hoffe, dass es dadurch besser geworden ist.

Comment: @Matthias: Im schriftlichen Gebrauch empfinde ich "möge" aber dann auch eher als scherzhaft, da eine Form "übertriebener Feierlichkeit" ausgedrückt wird. Wenn man beispielsweise den Satz aus der Antwort, "Wer einen besseren Vorschlag hat, möge diesen den Verantwortlichen kundtun.", liest, stellt man sich, wie ich finde, geradezu bildlich vor, wie die Verantwortlichen im königlichen Pelzmantel in ihrem Schloss sitzen, und der Eindruck wird durch das veraltete "kundtun" noch verstärkt. Die "natürliche", "neutrale" Formulierung wäre: "Wir bitten darum, dass bessere Vorschläge den ...

Comment: ... Verantwortlichen mitgeteilt werden." Und auch gerade die von dir genannten Gratulationskarten sind ja bewusst meist nicht so vollkommen todernst gehalten.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das mag für Dich und Dein Umfeld gelten. Ich empfinde "möge" in diesen Kontexten als völlig natürlich und bin mir sicher, dass diejenigen, die das in den mir vorliegenden Beispielen benutzt haben, auch ernst und neutral gemeint haben. Der Beispielsatz, den Jan inzwischen seiner Antwort hinzugefügt haben, ist vielleicht konstruiert und bekommt seinen leicht monarchischen Anstrich mindestens so sehr von "kundtun" wie von "möge". Das spricht in meinen Augen aber nicht gegen "möge" generell.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Zwei real-life-Beispiele aus meinem Posteingang: "Also wer noch nicht mit X gesprochen hat, möge mir durchgeben: [Liste]". "Wer zum Grillbüfett etwas beisteuern will, möge sich bitte mit mir vorher kurz abstimmen."